# How to render a page with instance variable with a hash anchor

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can render a `@comment` by

`redirect_to @comment`  which `id=35`

So the url may redirect to `SITE/comments/35`

But what if I want to add anchor to the url `SITE/comments/35#title`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`redirect_to comment_path(@comment, anchor: "title")`

http://blog.betterapps.nl/2012/09/12/30/rails-tip-how-to-add-an-anchor-to-a-redirect_to/